# Can't play video from AVCaptureFileOutput

Tags: xcode, swift3, avfoundation

I can't play the video the comes from the AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate. I think I'm missing something here's my code.

```
   func recordVideo() {
            let recordingDelegate: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self
            self.session!.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
            self.session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp")

            videoFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
        }
```

and on the delegate.

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {

        if error == nil {
            print("Play: \(outputFileURL!)")
            self.playVideo(path: outputFileURL!)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
        return
    }
```

But the video is not playing. I think I'm missing the file name or something. Pls help. Thanks!